# iterate two list simultaeneously in velocity template

Tags: java, arraylist, velocity

I have two arraylist in velocity template. I need to iterate both simultaneously like in java

```
for(int i=0; i< fooList.size(), barList.size; i++ ){
  System.ou.println(fooList.get(i))
 }
```

I tried below code but it is not working.

```
#foreach($foo in $fooList,$bar in barList)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such option in Velocity that can help us iterate multiple Collections simultaneously.

Further, the only loop available is the `#foreach` loop which can iterate only over an instance of `Iteratable`, so we cannot use the `Iterators` as well.

But you can still do something like this:

```
#foreach($list1Item in $list1)

    #set ( $count = ($velocityCount - 1) )

    #if ( $count != $list2.size() )
        #set ( $list2Item = $list2.get($count) )
    #else 
        #break
    #end

    $list1Item | $list2Item

#end
```

This would iterate both lists simultaneously and the number of iterations is equal to the size of smaller list.

Comment: Thx brother. Accepted your answer. Just want an information. Do you know any tool/online tool for testing velocity templates realtime?

Comment: @Ijaz nope. But I have made myself a simple application, so whenever I need to test it, I just use it. Ez ;) Also dont forget to upvote so that future comers will find the correct answer easily (and to earn me a +rep :P )

Comment: Done. I knw its too much too ask but is it possible to share us the app or host it. Because we are finding it difficult to test it. my mail is ijaz20@gmail.com. Thx anyways for ur help.

Comment: Ah yea sure. I will release the app on my git ;)